# DVD drive not detected in BIOS / Windows XP

Tags: windows, bios, dvd, hardware-failure, optical-drive

My parents bought a PC (a old Hewlett Packard Bell Pentium 4) just to watch YouTube. It worked well for months but last week, the DVD drives (there a 2 dvd drives) are no more recognized by the BIOS and Windows, but we can still open/close them.

I tried changing cables and did whatever resources I found on internet about UpperFilters & LowerFilters in regedit; but nothing helped.

Comment: It sounds like the IDE controller has failed.  You should be able to replace the drives with a USB Device on the cheap.  Based on the fact the computer is worth less then the USB Device, it would likely not possible to replace the IDE Drives ( replaced with SATA Drivers on the market ) you might be better of replacing the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting BIOS to defaults.

Generally if the drives are not detected in the BIOS, it's because:

- they are not hooked up correctly (cable not completely on drive or on motherboard, if you are using unkeyed IDE cables you might be "off by one pin")
- bad cable
- jumpers on drives are incorrect
- failed firmware update
- other IDE/SATA device is faulty - a failing hard drive could cause other drives to fail to detect on same channel, but it's not likely
- drive is indeed faulty